# SwiftUI struct init shorthand is confusing

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm working my way through the beginning [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) on the Apple Developer website. The example program uses a `NavigationLink`, like so:

```
NavigationLink {
    LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
} label: {
    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
}
```

I understand what this code does, but I don't understand the "label:" syntax. This seems to be some sort of initialization shorthand. For example, I found that the above can be rewritten as:

```
NavigationLink(destination: { LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark) },
               label: { LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark) })
```

But I cannot do something like this:

```
NavigationLink {
    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
} destination: {
    LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
}
```

It gives me a compile error:

> Type '() -> LandmarkDetail' cannot conform to View

Why does it work the first way, but not this way? I thought maybe it was because "destination:" is the first init() argument, but there are other overloaded inits in which it isn't, and I can't make it work with those either even though they seem to follow the same logic.

Comment: "I thought maybe it was because "destination:" is the first init() argument" Yeah, you can't just pass the parameters in any order you want. "but there are other overloaded inits in which it isn't" Which other init are you trying to call instead?

Comment: ViewBuilder wants a closure that returns a View not the View itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialiser that you are calling is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(destination:label:)-27n7s).

```
init(@ViewBuilder destination: () -> Destination, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
```

Notice that the last parameters of the initialiser are all function types (in fact, those are the only parameters in this case). For such a parameter list, you can pass closures for these parameters using the [trailing closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures#Trailing-Closures) syntax, i.e. writing the closure outside the `()`, where you would normally pass non-function type parameters. (But in this case there are no non-function type parameters, so you don't even need the `()`)

For the first closure written with the trailing closure syntax, you don't need to write its argument label, but for the rest of them, you do need to write their argument labels. That's why you don't need `destination:`, but you do need `label:`.

Another example:

```
func foo(p: Int, x: () -> Void, y: () -> Void, z: () -> Void) { }
```

This can be called like this:

```
foo(p: 1) {
    // this is the closure for the x parameter...
} y: {
    // this is the closure for the y parameter...
} z: {
    // this is the closure for the z parameter...
}
```

You can also only start using trailing closures for `y`, in which case you don't need to write `y:`:

```
foo(p: 1, x: { /*closure for x*/ }) {
    // closure for y
} z: {
    // closure for z
}
```

See also the [language reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions#Function-Call-Expression) about this:

> A function call expression can include trailing closures in the form of closure expressions immediately after the closing parenthesis. The trailing closures are understood as arguments to the function, added after the last parenthesized argument. The first closure expression is unlabeled; any additional closure expressions are preceded by their argument labels.

---

This is invalid:

```
NavigationLink {
    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
} destination: {
    LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
}
```

because there is no initialiser that:

- takes a two parameters, and
- both parameters are function types, and
- the second parameter is labelled `destination`

Answer (score 1):

If you take look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink), you will see 2 inits that have `destination` as the second argument:

1. `init(LocalizedStringKey, destination: () -> Destination)`
2. `init<S>(S, destination: () -> Destination) where S: StringProtocol`

None of the above takes a closure as its first argument as seen in your example. In addition to that, they take a `String` instead of a `View`.

The correct way of using them is something like this:

```
NavigationLink("Tap Me!") {
    LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)
}
```