# Explain how this useful extension of Binding works in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I recently came across this extention to `Binding` and I am having trouble understanding how it works.

```swift
extension Binding where Value == Bool {
    
    init<T>(value: Binding<T?>) {
        self.init {
            value.wrappedValue != nil
        } 
        set: { newValue in
            if !newValue {
                value.wrappedValue = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Its purpose I understand. It's designed to enable you to use a `Binding` for an Optional value as the trigger for `.alert(...)` or `.sheet(...)`.

For example:

```swift
struct ExampleView : View {
    
    @State var message: String? = nil
    @State var showIt: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Message") {
            message = "Some kind of message"
        }.alert("Alert!", isPresented: Binding(value: $message)) { // <---- used here
            Text(message!)
        }
    }
}
```

I've never seen the use of `self.init { ... }` inside of an initializer. I'm also confused by the use of `set: { ... }` in the initializer.  Please help me understand these language semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialiser in the extension must call an existing initialiser, or assign something to `self`. How else is it going to initialiser a `Binding`, after all?

The initialiser declared in the extension is calling [this existing initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(get:set:)-7ufcp) of `Binding`, which takes closure parameters called `get` and `set`. Note that `set` isn't part of some special syntax - it's just a parameter name.

The call to `self.init` is using the trailing closure syntax, described [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions#Function-Call-Expression) in the language reference. This syntax allows you to omit the parameter label of the first parameter. I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76445211/5133585) that goes into more detail.

You see this syntax everywhere in SwiftUI, whenever you initialise views, like:

```
Button {
    // do something
} label: {
    Text("Foo")
}
```

You are calling the [`Button.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/init(action:label:)) that takes an `action` and a `label`. Notice that the `action:` parameter label is omitted.

Finally, while this extension is useful for `alert`s, [`sheet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) has a version that takes in an `item: Binding<Item?>`, so you don't need to use this extension for `sheet`s.

Comment: Thank you for this.  What I missed was the fact that `set` was a parameter name and not some kind of fancy language syntax.  Now that you've explained it, its rather obvious ... you are absolutely right .. its used everywhere in SwiftUI.  Thanks again for taking the time to explain.